# is it possible in SQL to call two difrent table with difrent data at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, inner-join, average

so basicly what i need is to get two tables at the same time and then use a condition that reside in the first table and i want to apply it to the second one
if it not possible do i need to call SELECT Twice ?
is this code right ?
to determine the average rating of all movies released in 2012

```
SELECT AVG(rating),year FROM ratings , movies
   WHERE year = 2012;
//these are the tables that i have 

CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

Comment: It's perfectly possible: it's called a "join". Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: i just changed the code i included the table of the data that i have i need to determine the average rating of all movies released in 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `JOIN` and an aggregate function:

```
SELECT AVG(r.rating) avg_rating_2012
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN movies m on m.id = r.movie_id
WHERE m.year = 2012;
```

If you want this for all years at once, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m.year, AVG(r.rating) avg_rating
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN movies m on m.id = r.movie_id
GROUP BY m.year;
```